# no statement parsed and wrong number or types of arguments - cfstoredproc

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, coldfusion, cfstoredproc

I have an Oracle procedure - editBacklog which I'm calling from a CFM page via cfstoredproc.  After several **changes to the procedure** I started getting **ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'EDITBACKLOG'**.  I've gotten this before and found that if I changed the name of the procedure it starts working again.  I changed the name to editBacklog2 and it worked as I expected it to.  I changed the name back to editBacklog and got the same error.  I changed the name back to editBacklog2 again and started getting **ORA-01003: no statement parsed**.  NOTHING has changed at this point except for the names.  I changed the name yet again to editBacklog3 and it works as expected.

As of right now
editBacklog = ORA-06550
editBacklog2 = ORA-01003
editBacklog3 = works (kinda)

This whole thing started when I was trying to fix an ORA-01821: date format not recognized error.  I fear when I start changing things I'll start getting the same lame behavior described above.

Either Oracle or CF is messing with me and I'll end up liking one of them less because of it.

I assume it's probably cfstoredproc caching metadata or something but neither google, livedocs, or OTN have much to say about my situation.

I'm not the SA or DBA.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: edit: changed "after several edits" to "after several changes to the procedure" just to be clear.

Comment: Well, I'm sure it's a caching issue, probably with CFStoredProc. I just got back from lunch and editBacklog, editBacklog2, and editBacklog3 all work as expected. Once it happens again I'll try to find some way to clear the cache and report back.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ColdFusion caches some stuff when dealing with the database.

Two suggestions:

1. Disable/re-enable the database connection in the ColdFusion Administrator (Data Source, Show Advanced Settings, Disable Connections checkbox)
2. Go into whatever administration module you have for your database and kill the sessions from ColdFusion

Either way, re-establishing the connection will cause the Stored Proc to be re-cached.

Comment: Thanks, Al.  Sadly I don't have access to any of the admin tools, as I said in my OP I'm not the SA or DBA.  I have a couple tricks I can try next time it happens.

Comment: ColdFusion Administrator isn't the database. Are you also locked out of that?

Comment: I couldn't do anything about it but wait but it WAS a cache issue. It wouldn't work before lunch but it was fine after lunch...