# Different results with cfstoredproc and cfquery

Tags: t-sql, coldfusion, coldfusion-8, cfquery, cfstoredproc

When I execute a stored proc via `cfstoredproc`, I am getting a different result than calling that stored proc via `cfquery`. I am passing in the same exact parameter values to each call. And also, when I run the stored proc in SQL Studio, I get the correct results (same as the cfquery).

Here's the `cfstoredproc` call

```
<cfstoredproc datasource="#request.mainDSN#" debug="#request.debug#" procedure="rankingresults">
   <cfprocparam type="in" value="8652" CFSQLType="CF_SQL_INTEGER">
   <cfprocparam type="in" value="50" CFSQLType="CF_SQL_INTEGER">
   <cfprocparam type="in" value="53" CFSQLType="CF_SQL_INTEGER">
   <cfprocresult name="local.listing">
</cfstoredproc>
```

Here is the `cfquery` call

```
<cfquery datasource="#request.mainDSN#" name="rankings">
   EXEC rankingresults
    @CityZipId = 8652,
    @distance = 50,
    @sic = 53
</cfquery>
```

The results are completely different. It's not even close. I've been banged my head over this for several hours, and I can't figure out why it is doing what it is doing.

**UPDATE**

The stored proc is massive (and one that I inherited), so I'm not going to paste it all here: http://pastebin.com/EtufPWXf

Comment: please include the stored proc. Along with the results from each call.

Comment: Post the body/source of the actual stored procedure, please.

Comment: Does the procedure have any optional parameters?

Comment: Has the procedure changed recently? it's possible that cfstoredproc is running a cached version where cfquery is not.  I've seen that with PL/SQL. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2951244/no-statement-parsed-and-wrong-number-or-types-of-arguments-cfstoredproc

Comment: cfstoredproc uses postional parameters.  What happens if you run "exec rankingresults 8652, 50, 53" in cfquery?

Comment: Have you run trace inside the proc call to see what SQL string is actually getting executed?

Comment: @DanBracuk no difference.

Comment: @commadelimited H0w does one do that?

Comment: Fire up the MS SQL Profiler and/or enable tracing in your CF datasource and check the log file output.

Comment: @RHPT - Looks like it does have optional parameters. So your `cfstoredproc` call may not be passing in the values you think it is. Based on the order, it looks like it is actually passing in values for: `@CityZipID, @Sic, @lastRank`. As mentioned, cfstoredproc uses positional notation, so you need to supply all of the parameter values *in the correct order*.

Comment: @Leigh That was it! I can't believe I missed that.

Comment: if you run "exec rankingresults 8652, 50, 53" directly against your db (outside of coldfusion), do your results resemble anything you got from ColdFusion?

Comment: @DanBracuk The problem, like you are implying, is that the positioning of my parameters were incorrect. Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

(From the comments)

Looks like it does have optional parameters. So your `cfstoredproc` call may not be passing in the values you think it is. Based on the order, it looks like it is actually passing in values for: `@CityZipID, @Sic, @lastRank`. As Dan mentioned (and I hinted at), cfstoredproc uses positional notation for parameters ([@dbVarName is deprecated](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=Tags_p-q_14.html)). You need to supply all of the parameter values *in the correct order*.

**Update:**

FWIW, if you create a shell procedure you would see the cfstoredproc and cfquery are actually invoking the procedure with different parameters/values. (See below).

You would definitely see a difference in results if you invoked the procedure without the named parameters as @Dan suggested ie `exec rankingresults 8652, 50, 53`. (I know you said there was "no change", but there was probably just an error in your test).

**CFSTOREDPROC**

```
@ATTRCODES|@CITYZIPID|@DISTANCE|@HASURL |@ISFEATURED |@LASTRANK|@PHOTOCOUNT|@REVIEWCOUNT |@SIC|@SICBUDGETIDS 
(nothing)| 8652| (nothing)| (nothing)| (nothing)| 53| (nothing)| (nothing)| 50| (nothing)
```

**CFQUERY**

```
@ATTRCODES|@CITYZIPID|@DISTANCE|@HASURL |@ISFEATURED |@LASTRANK|@PHOTOCOUNT|@REVIEWCOUNT |@SIC|@SICBUDGETIDS 
(nothing)| 8652| 50| (nothing)| (nothing)| 0| (nothing)| (nothing)| 53| (nothing)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you run this directly on the sql server how many results does it return?  You could be returning multiple results that could explain the difference in behavior.